# Recorded track capacity of Garmin eTrex n0 devices

Tags: gpx, garmin, tracklog

I am interested in purchasing a Garmin eTrex 10 or 20 primarily for geotagging the photos I take on holiday, although I suppose the other features might come in handy as well in the future. When using the device for geotagging I would (like to) record my movements during a day and save them to a .gpx file and copy the .gpx file to my laptop at the end of the day when I process my photos, of course I would clear the storage of the Garmin then too. I think a track point interval of 5 m or 5 s would suffice for my use. Unfortunately I am a bit confused about the capacity of the eTrex n0 devices. According to the Garmin website a/the track log can consist of 10 000 track points on both the eTrex 10 and 20(x). However it isn't clear to me what this means. Does this mean every track can consist of not more than 10 000 track points? Or is this a total?
Several people on several forums have claimed that this is the total amount of track points for all tracks the device(s) can store.

Edit:
According to [Outdoor Gear Lab - The Best Handheld GPS Review](http://www.outdoorgearlab.com/Handheld-Gps-Reviews) the 10 000 is in fact the amount of points **per track**.

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. Please take the [tour] to learn about how to ask a focused question. There are at least 3 questions here.

Comment: You should make your edit into a (self-) answer, that's useful information for anyone considering the same device.